# Filter only specific strings from a column in R

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a dataset with a column that has comma separated values. I need to parse through each value in this column and keep only specific values and delete the others.

The code and data that I have for this is:

```
myDf <- structure(list(GeogPreferences = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Central and East Europe, Europe, North America, West Europe, US", 
"Europe, North America, West Europe, US", "Global, North America", 
"Northeast, Southeast, West, US"), class = "factor")), .Names = "GeogPreferences", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

 regionInterest <- c("Americas", "North America", "US", "Northeast","Southeast","West","Midwest","Southwest")
 k<-lapply(as.character(myDf$GeogPreferences),function(x) {
   z<-trimws(unlist(strsplit(x,split = ",")))
   z <- ifelse((z %in% regionInterest), z[z %in% regionInterest], z)
 })
 myDf$GeogPreferences<-unlist(k)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "GeogPreferences", value = c("Central and East Europe",
: replacement has 15 rows, data has 4
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
    GeogPreferences
1   Central and East Europe, Europe, North America, West Europe, US
2   Europe, North America, West Europe, US
3   Global, North America
4   Northeast, Southeast, West, US
```

If the column has any on the strings from `regionInterest`, I want to keep that string, else I want to delete it.

The output I am expecting is:

```
    GeogPreferences
1   North America, US
2   North America, US
3   North America
4   Northeast, Southeast, West, US
```

Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably *first* split the data *and only then* run the subset. 
This will both improve efficiency (because `strsplit` it is vectorized) and the size of the vector in each split won't matter. Also, no need in `trimws`, it just makes your code inefficient. Instead, split on `", "` while specifying `fixed = TRUE`. This will make `strsplit` work about X10 times faster as it won't use regex in order to split.

The following works using base R only

```
do.call(rbind, # you can use `rbind.data.frame` instead if you don't want a matrix
        lapply(strsplit(as.character(myDf$GeogPreferences), ", ", fixed = TRUE), 
               function(x) toString(x[x %in% regionInterest])))
#     [,1]                            
# [1,] "North America, US"             
# [2,] "North America, US"             
# [3,] "North America"                 
# [4,] "Northeast, Southeast, West, US"
```

---

Though the above solution (similarly to your own) is still a rowwise one. Instead, we could try to achieve the same effect by operating columnwise. And by "columnwise" I mean that if we will operate on a transposed split, the number of iterations will be of the size of the longest sentence in `myDf$GeogPreferences` (the number of the commas we split by) which should be significantly smaller than the number of rows in the data.

Her's an illustration using `data.table::tstrsplit`

```
tmp <- data.table::tstrsplit(myDf$GeogPreferences, ", ", fixed = TRUE)
res <- do.call(paste, 
               c(sep = ", ", 
                 lapply(tmp, function(x) replace(x, !x %in% regionInterest, NA_character_))))
gsub("NA, |, NA", "", res)
# [1] "North America, US" "North America, US" "North America" "Northeast, Southeast, West, US"
```

---

Here is simple benchmark on 100K rows data set

```
bigDF <- myDf[sample(nrow(myDf), 1e5, replace = TRUE),, drop = FALSE]

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

tidyverse <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    separate_rows(GeogPreferences, sep = ",") %>% 
    mutate(GeogPreferences = trimws(GeogPreferences)) %>% 
    filter(GeogPreferences %in% c("Americas", "North America", "US", "Northeast","Southeast","West","Midwest","Southwest")) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarize(GeogPreferences = toString(trimws(GeogPreferences))) %>% 
    select(-id) 

}

MF <- function(x) {
    k <- lapply(as.character(x$GeogPreferences), function(x) {
      z <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, split = ",")))
      z <- z[z %in% regionInterest] 
    })
    sapply(k, paste, collapse = ", ")
}


DA1 <- function(x) {
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(strsplit(as.character(x$GeogPreferences), ", ", fixed = TRUE), 
                 function(x) toString(x[x %in% regionInterest])))
}

DA2 <- function(x) {
  tmp <- data.table::tstrsplit(x$GeogPreferences, ", ", fixed = TRUE)
  res <- do.call(paste, 
                 c(sep = ", ", 
                   lapply(tmp, function(x) replace(x, !x %in% regionInterest, NA_character_))))
  gsub("NA, |, NA", "", res)
}

system.time(tidyverse(bigDF))
# user  system elapsed 
# 17.67    0.01   17.91 
system.time(MF(bigDF))
# user  system elapsed 
# 15.52    0.00   15.70 
system.time(DA1(bigDF))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.97    0.00    1.00 
system.time(DA2(bigDF))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.25    0.00    0.25
```

So the other two solutions ran over 15 secs compared to my both solutions that ran less than a second

Comment: Thanks David!! This helps.

Comment: That's a nice comparison. Thanks David. What would I need to do if I need to make the changes to an existing column and save it back to the dataset? I get this error even after using rbind.data.frame.    `Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
Problem variables: 'Geographic.Preferences'`

Comment: Just assign it back. For instance, `myDf$GeogPreferences <- gsub("NA, |, NA", "", res)` (for the second solution). Re your edit, don't use `rbind.data.frame` if you want a vector back. Just do `myDf$GeogPreferences <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(myDf$GeogPreferences), ", ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) toString(x[x %in% regionInterest])))`

Comment: I checked that it works fine when I reassign it. I have a problem with my code at some other line. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The error that you're getting is due to `strsplit` creating more rows than your input df.  Also in your `ifelse` statement, you're returning z on `FALSE` so it's not doing what you intended.

Here's a `tidyr`/`dplyr` solution to your problem.

```
myDf %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(GeogPreferences, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(GeogPreferences = trimws(GeogPreferences)) %>% 
  filter(GeogPreferences %in% c("Americas", "North America", "US", "Northeast","Southeast","West","Midwest","Southwest")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(GeogPreferences = toString(trimws(GeogPreferences))) %>% 
  select(-id) 


# A tibble: 4 × 1
                 GeogPreferences
                           <chr>
1              North America, US
2              North America, US
3                  North America
4 Northeast, Southeast, West, US
```

Comment: Thanks Jake!! This helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a solution closer to your approach change it to

```
regionInterest <- c("Americas", "North America", "US",
  "Northeast","Southeast","West","Midwest","Southwest")
k<-lapply(as.character(myDf$GeogPreferences),function(x) {
  z<-trimws(unlist(strsplit(x,split = ",")))
# this makes sure you only use z which are in regionInterest
  z <- z[z %in% regionInterest] 
})
# paste with collapse creates one value out of a vector of string seperated by the collapse argument
myDf$GeogPreferences<-sapply(k, paste, collapse = ", ")
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Marc!! This helps.